# How to show polygon and polyine using google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google maps api , i have some POLYGONS and POLYINES.
i'm trying to show both (polygon and polyline) in google maps api.
I'm tried something, but not able not show both polygons and polyline, only polygons is showing ,how to show both Polygons and polylines.I have a Json that json have source polygon or polyline, that source based i'm showing here.sorry for my english.
 Hopefully someone can kindly let me know where I am failing .
 Here is my code .[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/varunphp/oeqmgp7q/1/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 450px;" id="map-canvas"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(13.09084815771412,80.26878878474236);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: centerPoint,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var arr = new Array();
    var polygons = [];
    var polyline = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var coordinates = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker;
    var getBounds;


    var data = '[{"name":"Arumbakkam","id":"1620","source":"polygon","latlng":[{"lat":"13.080648730311745","lng":"80.2668146789074"},{"lat":"13.081819177841483","lng":"80.27453944087029"},{"lat":"13.086208306590859","lng":"80.27172848582268"},{"lat":"13.09084815771412","lng":"80.26878878474236"},{"lat":"","lng":null}]},{"name":"Chetpet","id":"1621","source":"polyline","latlng":[{"lat":"13.119271","lng":"80.095053"},{"lat":"13.117557","lng":"80.095203"},{"lat":"13.116408","lng":"80.101683"}]}]';
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var polName = jsonData[i].name;
        var id = jsonData[i].id;
        var latArr = jsonData[i].latlng;
        var source_d = jsonData[i].source;
        arr = [];
        for (j = 0; j < latArr.length; j++) {
            var lat = latArr[j].lat;
            var lng = latArr[j].lng;

            arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)));
            bounds.extend(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        }

       if(source_d == "polygon"){

        polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
            auto_id: i,
            id: id,
            name: polName,
            paths: arr,
            Source: source_d,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            zIndex: 10
        }));
        console.log(id+" polygons name="+polName);
        polygons[polygons.length - 1].setMap(map);

       }else if (source_d == "polyline") {  
             polyline.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                auto_id: i,
                id: id,
                name: polName,
                paths: arr,
                Source: source_d,
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                 zIndex: 11
            }));
            polyline[polyline.length - 1].setMap(map);
           console.log(id+" polyline  name="+polName);
      }  

    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [google.maps.PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolylineOptions) object doesn't have a `paths` property, that is only valid for a [google.maps.PolygonOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolygonOptions) object.

Change:

```
polyline.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
    auto_id: i,
    id: id,
    name: polName,
    paths: arr,
    Source: source_d,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    zIndex: 11
  }));
```

To:

```
polyline.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
    auto_id: i,
    id: id,
    name: polName,
    path: arr,
    Source: source_d,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    zIndex: 11
  }));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/m0y7zbk0/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  initialize();
});

function initialize() {
  var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(13.09084815771412, 80.26878878474236);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: centerPoint,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var arr = new Array();
  var polygons = [];
  var polyline = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var coordinates = [];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker;
  var getBounds;


  var data = '[{"name":"Arumbakkam","id":"1620","source":"polygon","latlng":[{"lat":"13.080648730311745","lng":"80.2668146789074"},{"lat":"13.081819177841483","lng":"80.27453944087029"},{"lat":"13.086208306590859","lng":"80.27172848582268"},{"lat":"13.09084815771412","lng":"80.26878878474236"}]},{"name":"Chetpet","id":"1621","source":"polyline","latlng":[{"lat":"13.119271","lng":"80.095053"},{"lat":"13.117557","lng":"80.095203"},{"lat":"13.116408","lng":"80.101683"}]}]';
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    var polName = jsonData[i].name;
    var id = jsonData[i].id;
    var latArr = jsonData[i].latlng;
    var source_d = jsonData[i].source;
    arr = [];
    for (j = 0; j < latArr.length; j++) {
      var lat = latArr[j].lat;
      var lng = latArr[j].lng;

      arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)));
      bounds.extend(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    }

    if (source_d == "polygon") {

      polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
        auto_id: i,
        id: id,
        name: polName,
        paths: arr,
        Source: source_d,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        zIndex: 10
      }));
      console.log(id + " polygons name=" + polName);
      polygons[polygons.length - 1].setMap(map);

    } else if (source_d == "polyline") {
      polyline.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
        auto_id: i,
        id: id,
        name: polName,
        path: arr,
        Source: source_d,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        zIndex: 11
      }));
      polyline[polyline.length - 1].setMap(map);
      console.log(id + " polyline  name=" + polName);
    }

  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```